# Update parent entity change child entity collection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

I use Entity framework Core in a WPF application.

I have a model like this :

Parent_Entity
      _ Id
      _ Collection of Child_Entity
      _ Current_Child_Entity (not mapped)

The Current_Child_Entity is one of the collection. For exemple :

**Collection of Child Entity** :
child1
child2

**Current_Child_Entity** :
child2

When I try to save a change I do something like this :

1) AddOrUpdate(Current_Child_Entity)
2) AddOrUpdate(Parent_Entity)

The AddOrUpdate() method that I used is implemented this way :

```
public void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
        {
            if (!Context.Set<T>().Any(obj => obj == entity))
            {
                Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                Update(entity);
            }
        }
```

My issue is when I do the first update (with Current_Child_Entity), all seems good.

But when I go in the second update where I save the parent entity, **it add a duplication of two Child_Entity with the same Id, the same properties** in Collection of Child Entity. For exemple, if I updated child2 in the Collection Of Child Entity I get :
child1
child2
child2

It does this when I do in AddOrUpdate() :

Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

Why a duplication of a Child Entity is done in the Collection at this instruction ?

There are something that I don't understand and could you explain me what I doing wrong ?

Thank's for the help.

Comment: Seems like you have a Problem with references, can you do Equals instead of ==?

Comment: Many thanks, you got the good hint for the problem. There was a problem with references. I solved my issue in correcting this. Thank you !